# GoDaddy hosting wp-admin problem

Tags: wp-admin, login, hosting

I'm having a big issue with /wp-admin login page on GoDaddy Hosting Account (Windows).

I can't log in if I visit the following url. I get re-directed to the login page again.

- domain.com/wp-admin

I can log in if I use the following urls.

- domain.com/wp-admin/ (with the forward slash on the end)
- domain.com/admin
- domain.com/login

I pointed the domain I want to use to the installation of my wordpress, which is under a sub-directory of the root.

- Disabled permalinks (removed web.config which is I guess .htaccess for windows)
- Disabled plug-ins
- Verified Site URL in the database (It doesn't contain an extra forward slash)

When I log into wp-admin I am redirected to.

domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2F **sub-directory** %2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

The url is incorrect and the sub-directory should not be there.

Visiting wp-admin/ with the forward slash directs me to the correct url.

domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

GoDaddy Support does not see an issue here.

Comment: Oh, gee, why Windows?

Comment: It's not my hosting account, I suggested strongly against it. :/

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, try the following:

- Go to permalinks settings
- Change the setting selected
- Save
- Come back to permalinks settings
- Restore the setting selected
- Save

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This drove me pretty tense the whole morning finally I found out there was a security plug in that prevented me from logging in unless I was logged into my cpanel on the back end. Hope that helps.

The exact name of the plug is was *WPS Hide Login* that one of the developers had installed for security. I went into the back end cpanel on go daddy and it had a different link to be able to access the wp-admin section and make changes.